# Multi-instance and Loop in BPMN

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

I am trying to model a certain behaviour, where couple of activities in differents swimlanes supposed to be processed in a loop. Now BPMN uses tokens to ilustrate the flow and paths taken. I wonder how such tokens work in case of loops. Does every activity iteration creates a token which consequently travel through the connected activities?

E.g. Let's say Activity1 will be performed in a loop 10 times. Will that create 10 tokens where each will travel through the remaining activities of the process? Such behaviour would be undesirable, however if I am not mistaken multi-instance activities work that way.

The only solution on my mind which would comply with BPMN specification would be to create a Call activity for the whole block of activities and then run the Call activity in a loop.

Can anyone clarify for me the use of loops and multi-instances in BPMN from the view of tokens?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my reading of the documentation: https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF  The answer from @qwerty_so does not seem to conform to the standard, although in part this seems to be because the question also seems imprecise or at least underspecified.

A token (see glossary) is simply an imaginary object that represents the flow unit in the process diagram.  There are at least three different types of loops specified in the standard, which suggest different implications for the flow unit.
Sections 13.2.6 and 12.2.7 describe Loop Activity and Multiple Instance Activities respectively.  While the latter, on its face, might not seem like a loop, the standard defines attributes of the activity that suggest otherwise including: MultipleInstanceLoopCharacteristics and ExpressionloopCardinality.
In the former case, it seems that the operational semantics suggest a single flow unit that repeats multiple times according to some policy or even unbounded.
In the latter case, the activity has "multiple instances spawned," including a parallel variant.

That multiple instances can flow forward in parallel, on its face, suggests that the system must at least allow for the possibility of spawning multiple tokens (or conceptually splitting the original token) to support multiple threads proceeding simultaneously along different paths.

That said, the Loop Activity (13.2.6) appears to support the OP's desired semantics.

Comment: You may remove the reference since I retracted my answer.